# MVC Display Template for multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I had some html that was being generated in multiple views in trying to keep up with DRY principles, I moved it into a Display Template.

Because the different views have different Models, how could I make the Display Template generic? The property names are the same.

Say I have these 2 models:

```
public class ListModel
{
 public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
 public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
}

public class DisplayModel 
{
 public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
 public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

Here is my Display Template - How can I make this more generic - I need it to be able to accept any Model with the same property names?

```
@model ListModel
{
 if(Model.Prop1)
 {
  <div>Prop1!</div>
 }
 if(Model.Prop2)
 {
  <div>Prop2!</div>
 }
```

}

And these are my 2 views: List and Display

List:

```
@model ListModel

@DisplayFor(@Model, "CustomDisplayTemplate")
```

Display:

```
@model DisplayModel

@DisplayFor(@Model, "CustomDisplayTemplate") //will currently break as the custom display template expects a ListModel
```

Comment: You might be better of have a base (abstract) model class or interface that both view models inherit from and base the template on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an Interface with the two properties:

```
public interface ISameModel
{
 bool Prop1 { get; }
 bool Prop2 { get; }
}

public class ListModel : ISameModel
{
 public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
 public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
}

public class DisplayModel : ISameModel
{
 public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
 public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

and afterwards use this interface as the model in your template

```
@model ISameModel
```

Comment: Thanks, nice easy and elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the `UIHint` attribute. When this attribute is added to a model property, Razor will look for a view template with the same name.

```
[UIHint("MyCustomView")]
public class ListModel
{

    public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
    public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
}

[UIHint("MyCustomView")]
public class DisplayModel 
{
    public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
    public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

And you can put your custom view here `Views/DisplayTemplates/MyCustomView.cshtml`, note that the model type is now dynamic:

```
@model dynamic

@if(Model.Prop1)
{
    <div>Prop1!</div>
}
@if(Model.Prop2)
{
    <div>Prop2!</div>
}
```

You could also add a view for the editor template here `Views/EditorTemplates/MyCustomView.cshtml`.

Comment: It's a handy option if you are unable to change your base classes. The answer from @zahorak is probably preferable in this situation, though you could use both answers combined.